# Web.config Transformation: Transform attribute is not declared

Tags: visual-studio, web-config, web.config-transform

I am attempting to transform my *Web.config* file to add rewrite rules for release builds, but I'm getting an intellisense error.

> The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform:Transform' attribute is not declared.

**Web.Release.config**

[image: Web.Release.config]

It seems to compile okay without errors. But when I attempt to Publish, I do get build errors:

> No element in the source document matches '/configuration/system.webServer/rewrite'
>   The 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform:Transform' attribute is not declared.

The first line above is an error, while the second one is a warning. Why doesn't this work?

Note that the top of my *Web.config* does include the line `<configuration xmlns:xdt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform">`

**UPDATE:**

The build error when deploying turned out to be caused by something else. So, in fact, it *does* build okay and I can deploy. So at this point, the question is just about why this Intellisense error/warning is appearing.

Comment: have you tried to  `<add xdt:Transform="RemoveAll" />` before you do the `rewrite`? Else go to the `XML menu` choose `schemas` and find for `DotNetConfig.xsd` and choose use this schema. If this still doesn't work you could also try selecting the `RazorCustomSchema.xsd` and `EntityFrameworkConfig_6_1_0.xsd` schemas. If now it doesn't work, set in configuration the link as: `xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform"`. Also if you use that link in the broswer you can see `The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.`

Comment: Hi @Jonathan.  I'm afraid I don't have an answer, but it seems this question has been asked before. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059257/how-do-i-enable-intellisense-in-vs-2013-for-rewrite-in-transform-config

Comment: You could also try adding `<configSections>` to the `configuration` and also `<connectionStrings>`

Comment: Appears to be a defect in Intellisense.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059257/how-do-i-enable-intellisense-in-vs-2013-for-rewrite-in-transform-config

Comment: @Jonathan Wood: For me it cannot be published (VS2019). I am getting "namespace prefix xdt is not defined", how did you solve this?

Comment: @Muflix: Nothing to solve. It's an issue with Intellisense. Aside from the red squigglies, it still works as intended.

Comment: @Jonathan Wood I was able to build, but not able to publish the project via the publish wizard (the publish process stopped because of this error). But in the end I finally solved my issue with this approach https://stackoverflow.com/a/36836533/2333663

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As suggested in [How do I enable IntelliSense in VS 2013 for <rewrite> in transform .config?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059257/how-do-i-enable-intellisense-in-vs-2013-for-rewrite-in-transform-config) this is a defect in Intellisense.

- If you're using VS 2017 open "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Xml\Schemas\1033\DotNetConfig.xsd".
- Locate the `xs:element name="rewrite"` element near the end of the file and copy

  ```
  <xs:anyAttribute namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/XML-Document-Transform" processContents="strict"/>
  ```

  to the end of the rewrite element.

As soon as I saved the file Visual Studio removed the warning squiggly.

[image]

Someone should probably raise this with the Visual Studio team.

Comment: I've raised the issue through Visual Studio Feedback. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/67412/intellisense-issue-rewrite-transform.html

Comment: This still appears to happen in VS 2019, but the fix doesn't fix it.

Comment: @Neo: Were you able to get around the above problem?

Comment: @user527614 Not that I recall, but it's been a while since I worked with Web.config files now.

Comment: Appears also in VS 2022